# How do I print a Legal document using the DevExpress PdfViewerControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, printing, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have the following PdfViewerControl in a WPF dialog:

```
            <dxpdf:PdfViewerControl Grid.Column="0"
                                Name="Viewer"
                                CommandBarStyle="None"
                                ZoomMode="FitToWidth"
                                Margin="5">

            <dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.RibbonTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <dxb:BarManager x:Name="PART_PdfBarManager">
                            <dxb:BarManager.Items>
                                <dxpdf:PrintDocumentBarItem Name="bPrint"
                                                            Command="{Binding Path=(dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.ActualViewer).ActualCommandProvider.PrintDocumentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

                            </dxb:BarManager.Items>
                            <DockPanel>

                                <dxr:RibbonControl AllowCustomization="False"
                                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                                   RibbonHeaderVisibility="Collapsed"
                                                   RibbonStyle="Office2010"
                                                   ToolbarShowMode="Hide"
                                                   ShowApplicationButton="false"
                                                   Height="80">
                                    <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                                        <dxr:RibbonPage>

                                            <dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                                <dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="bPrint" />
                                            </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>

                                        </dxr:RibbonPage>
                                    </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                                </dxr:RibbonControl>
                                <dxpdf:PdfPresenterControl
                                    BehaviorProvider="{Binding Path=(dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.ActualViewer).ActualBehaviorProvider, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Document="{Binding Path=(dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.ActualViewer).Document, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    CurrentPageNumber="{Binding Path=(dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.ActualViewer).CurrentPageNumber, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    AllowCachePages="False"
                                    IsSearchControlVisible="{Binding Path=(dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.ActualViewer).IsSearchControlVisible, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </dxb:BarManager>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxpdf:PdfViewerControl.RibbonTemplate>

        </dxpdf:PdfViewerControl>
```

I bind the DocumentSource to a stream of a PDF file that has a Legal page size (8.5 x 14).  When I print from the PdfViewerControl, the resulting PDF always has a Letter page size (8.5 x 11).  What settings am I missing for the PdfViewerControl PrintCommand?  Is there a way to force it to use Legal?  Or, at least to pull the page size from the PDF document?

Comment: Side question but have you tried addressing this issue directly to Devexpress support? From my experience they are SUPER responsive and very clear

Comment: I have submitted a ticket, but I hadn't heard back yet (it's been several hours) so I thought I'd post it here, too, just in case someone had some experience with it and could get back to me sooner.  Plus, I like the interface of StackOverflow better and it's easier to search.  I'll post an answer when and if I get a solution from DevExpress.